# error in twitter oauth

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I have got ' in my name in the twitter.It gives the following error while logging with the twitter.

```
string(12) "twitteroauth"
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1127010722
    [id_str] => 1127010722
    [name] => Mahima  o'  Maharjan
    [screen_name] => maharjahmahima
    [location] => 
    [description] => 
    [url] => 
    [entities] => stdClass Object
        (
            [description] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [urls] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [protected] => 
    [followers_count] => 8
    [friends_count] => 77
    [listed_count] => 0
    [created_at] => Mon Jan 28 04:38:26 +0000 2013
    [favourites_count] => 5
    [utc_offset] => 
    [time_zone] => 
    [geo_enabled] => 
    [verified] => 
    [statuses_count] => 7
    [lang] => en
    [status] => stdClass Object
        (
            [created_at] => Wed Aug 07 14:30:34 +0000 2013
            [id] => 365117770263830529
            [id_str] => 365117770263830529
            [text] => #Twitition Get The "Zayn Did 9/11" Song Off Of The itunes Store. http://t.co/kq8bGwJSjP
            [source] => Twitition
            [truncated] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
            [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
            [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
            [geo] => 
            [coordinates] => 
            [place] => 
            [contributors] => 
            [retweet_count] => 0
            [favorite_count] => 0
            [entities] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [hashtags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [text] => Twitition
                                    [indices] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 0
                                            [1] => 10
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [symbols] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [urls] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [url] => http://t.co/kq8bGwJSjP
                                    [expanded_url] => http://twitition.com/j4ygh
                                    [display_url] => twitition.com/j4ygh
                                    [indices] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 65
                                            [1] => 87
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [user_mentions] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [favorited] => 
            [retweeted] => 
            [possibly_sensitive] => 
            [lang] => en
        )

    [contributors_enabled] => 
    [is_translator] => 
    [profile_background_color] => C0DEED
    [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
    [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
    [profile_background_tile] => 
    [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
    [profile_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png
    [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
    [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED
    [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
    [profile_text_color] => 333333
    [profile_use_background_image] => 1
    [default_profile] => 1
    [default_profile_image] => 1
    [following] => 
    [follow_request_sent] => 
    [notifications] => 
)
```

and following are the warnings

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json?id=1127010722)

 [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 

Unauthorized in /home/familyva/public_html/apps/config/functions.php on line 19
```

and

```
    Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in 

/home/familyva/public_html/apps/config/functions.php on line 20


    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

 server version for the right syntax to use near 'Maharjan','','','ma','http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_' at line 1
```

Comment: you have to use oauth for api 1.1

Comment: i have been using twitter oauth for api 1.1